# Identifying specific string and place it in the same index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension

Related to my previous post, would it be possible to separate the list of weirdly combined animals and their attribute (denoted in #)?

Dataset:

```
the_list = pd.Series([["dog", "cat", "#paws"],["gorilla"],["goat", "#beard","#hoofs"],["goldfish", "#fins", "#bigeyes", "#scales"]])
```

My Code:

```
category1 = []
category2 = []

for word_list in the_list:
    category1.append([{v : 1} for v in word_list if not "#" in v])
    category2.append([{v : 1} for v in word_list if "#" in v])
```

Here's the result:

Category 1:

```
[{'dog': 1}, {'cat': 1}, {'gorilla': 1}, {'goat': 1}, {'goldfish': 1}]
```

Category 2:

```
[[{'#paws': 1}],
 [],
 [{'#beard': 1}, {'#hoofs': 1}],
 [{'#fins': 1}, {'#bigeyes': 1}, {'#scales': 1}]]
```

But what I need is to join all the elements of the same index instead of creating a separate dictionary for them

Category1:

```
[{'dog': 1, 'cat': 1},
 {'gorilla': 1},
 {'goat': 1},
 {'goldfish': 1}]
```

Category2:

```
[{'#paws': 1}, # from dog, cat
 {'No Category 2': 1}, #from gorilla
 {"#beard" : 1,"#hoofs" : 1}, #from goat
 {'#fins': 1, '#bigeyes': 1, '#scales': 1}] #from goldfish
```

Comment: `[{v:1 for v in l if not v.startswith('#')} for l in the_list]` & `[{v:1 for v in l if v.startswith('#')} for l in the_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dict.fromkeys`:

```
category1 = []
category2 = []

for word_list in the_list:
    category1.append(dict.fromkeys([v for v in word_list if not '#' in v] or ['No Category 1'], 1))
    category2.append(dict.fromkeys([v for v in word_list if '#' in v] or ['No Category 2'], 1))
```

Output:

```
#category1
[{'cat': 1, 'dog': 1}, {'gorilla': 1}, {'goat': 1}, {'goldfish': 1}]

#category2
[{'#paws': 1},
 {'No Category 2': 1},
 {'#beard': 1, '#hoofs': 1},
 {'#bigeyes': 1, '#fins': 1, '#scales': 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, I just checked how dict.fromkeys work and I learned today

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict`

**Ex:**

```
category1 = []
category2 = []

the_list = pd.Series([["dog", "cat", "#paws"],["gorilla"],["goat", "#beard","#hoofs"],["goldfish", "#fins", "#bigeyes", "#scales"]])
for word_list in the_list:
    category1.append(dict((v , 1) for v in word_list if not "#" in v))
    category2.append(dict((v , 1) for v in word_list if "#" in v)  or {'No Category 2': 1})
```

**Output:**

```
[{'cat': 1, 'dog': 1}, {'gorilla': 1}, {'goat': 1}, {'goldfish': 1}]
[{'#paws': 1},
 {'No Category 2': 1},
 {'#beard': 1, '#hoofs': 1},
 {'#bigeyes': 1, '#fins': 1, '#scales': 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh I didn't know you can actually use dict few modification from my code